# could not create ssl/tls secure channel Windows Server 2016

Tags: .net, api, asp.net-web-api

I am creating an API to sign documents through Globalsign. I can sign perfectly with a signature on my own windows 10 pc. However when i publish it on my 2016 windows server, It throws the following exception:

```
Exception: mscorlib => An error occurred while sending the request.
--- StackTrace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at WebAPI.Models.ApiConnect.Login(String aURL, String aKey, String aSecret) in C:\Users\mao\Documents\GitHub\stadium\WebAPI\Models\Program.cs:line 64
   at WebAPI.Models.ApiConnect.GLobalsign(String naam, String club) in C:\Users\mao\Documents\GitHub\stadium\WebAPI\Models\Program.cs:line 399
   at WebAPI.Models.SignaturePad_Document_signed.TrySave(SignaturePad_Document_signed myDocument, Computer myDevice) in C:\Users\mao\Documents\GitHub\stadium\WebAPI\Models\SignaturePad_Documents.cs:line 212
--- InnerException ---
Exception: System => The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
--- StackTrace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
```

The code is as follows:

```
            string Json;

            var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(GsConfig.SslCertificatePath(), GsConfig.GetKeyPassword()));
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                using (HttpRequestMessage request1 = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), baseURL + "/login"))
                {
                    string body = "{\"api_key\": \"api_key\",\"api_secret\": \"api_secret\"}";
                    request1.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                    HttpResponseMessage response1 = httpClient.SendAsync(request1).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                    Json = response1.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
            }

            JObject accessCode = JObject.Parse(Json);

            return accessCode;
```

Does anyone have an idea or clue in which direction I should look( or the solution)?

Things I tried/checked: I have a pfx made with OpenSSL 1.1.1 because apparently the ones with OPenSSL 3.0.0 dont work. I checked the Windows event log, there was nothing. i tried

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I tried other clients and handlers, nothing changed.
Ive tried

```
handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.None;
```

The certificate is installed in my trusted root certificate authorities.
I checked the other questions like thisz one but they didn't bring me any solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently the cause was my IIS manager. In application pools, load user details stood on false. This needs to be on true.